# How to check the executor of a job with the Jenkins API?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent, jenkins-api

I was looking at the Jenkins api, specifically around jobs that have been previously executed on my Jenkins master.

Using the following code:

```
http://host/job/<job_name>/lastBuild/api/json
```

I can see the 'executor' field is 'null' when the job is run from the master, I assume that this value is updated with the name of the relevant node if I decide to setup and run from a slave? Is this the case?

I wonder why executor is null when intuitively I'd think it'd be some identifier for the master, like a name or something.

Answer (score 0):

I checked that And the executor is always "null" when looking at the Json,

even when it doesn't run on master.

e.g:

```
"executor":null,"fullDisplayName":"Infra-Maven-Upload-Nexus-Windows
```

Comment: So I guess I'm mistaken as to what that executor value actually means?